# Error upgrading WSSF solution to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2010, wssf

I've recently installed VS2010 and I'm trying to upgrade a project that I created using VS2008 and WSSF (Web Service Software Factory). I've installed the 2010 version of WSSF and it's prerequisites. After upgrading, when I try to load the solution I get "blah.ssfproduct cannot be opened because its project type (.ssfproduct) is not supported by this version of the application". Absolutely no idea what to do :(

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Factory for VS2008 has a custom project that holds the model files and the VS migration wizard doesn't know what to do with it. Fortunately, the 2010 version has changed this custom project to a normal C# class library project and all the model files can be added to it ('Add Existing") without modification. For the final release, we will include the few migration steps to keep everyone out of the woods. Sorry for not supplying it with our pre-release drops.

In case you haven't seen it, your question was also answered by a community member on the Service Factory community at http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=211726. The response includes steps that worked for one person and they seem solid to me too.

Cheers,
Don

Comment: Thanks VERY much for your advice Don. I had no chance of figuring that out that by myself. It's all working and I'm in my VS2010 happy place :)